# Setter Getter Method in Loop in Java

Tags: java

I have recently learned about Setters and Getters. I can use them but the problem is that I have to use them in a loop. Some of the code that I am using is mentioned below.

I am entering Student information in a loop, and then editing it in another loop using Set Get methods. I can use the setter and getter methods without the loop but I am not sure how to use them inside the loop. So please guide me to add students in a stu array.

```
    public static void   Addstudents()
    {   
      for(int i=0; i<stu.length; i++)
      {
        stu[i]=new Stuinfo();
        System.out.println("Enter name ");
        name= sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter id  ");
        id= sc.next();
      }
    }
```

And to edit the data, I want to run a loop and use the setter method to set the values. Something like this:

```
  public void Modify()
  { 
    String Cid; 
    System.out.println("You r modifying account");
    for (int i=0; i<stu.length;i++)
    { 
      stu[i].setId(id)...// dont know what to do in loop hree 
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not clear, I think that to modify a specific account of a single student, you need something like this :

```
   public void Modify() {   
    String Cid; 
    System.out.println("Enter your ID :");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int id = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i=0; i<stu.length;i++)
    {   
           if(id == stu[i].getId()) {
            //Change your account details
            System.out.println("Enter name ");
             name= sc.next();
             stu[i].setName(name);
            }

    }
     }
```

In the example above, you are getting an id as input, and then you are looking up in the array for the input id, and if you find one, you are giving the opportunity to the user to change the account details of that specific user ...

While in the first example you have to set your students instance properties using setters :

```
 public static void   Addstudents()
     {

     for(int i=0; i<stu.length; i++)
    {
    stu[i]=new Stuinfo();
    System.out.println("Enter name ");
    stu[i].setName( sc.next() );
    System.out.println("Enter id  ");
    stu[i].setId( sc.next() ); 


    }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped , i am beginner so was not able to mention it clearly

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Modify() {   
    System.out.println("You r  modifying account");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i=0; i<stu.length;i++)
    {   
        System.out.println("Enter id");
        stu[i].setId(sc.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Enter name ");
        stu[i].setName(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
```